# Proof $A \cap C \subseteq A \setminus (B\setminus C)$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

> Proof $A \cap C \subseteq A \setminus (B\setminus C)$

I proved this but I want to make sure that I used the correct steps in the proof:

Let $x \in A \cap C$

This means $x \in A \land x \in C$

Which will imply $x \in A \land (x \in C \lor x \notin B)$

Since $(x \in C \lor x \notin B)$ is equivalant to $\neg(x\notin C \land x\in B)$: $x \in A \land \neg(x\notin C \land x\in B)$

Simplifying to: $x \in A \land \neg(x\in B\setminus C)$

$x \in A \land x\notin B\setminus C$

Hence: $x\in A\setminus (B\setminus C)$

Therefore $A \cap C \subseteq A \setminus (B\setminus C)$

Comment: "*Which can be rewritten as*" is incorrect.  You can however replace it with "*Which will* **imply**"

Comment: Is it valid to assume that adding $\lor x \notin B$ would not change the original statement?

Comment: Apart from that one troublesome phrase, I see no other problem with the technical parts of the proof upon first review.  You could perhaps organize your thoughts a bit better, for example on the line "Since...is equivalent to..." by replacing the colon with a phrase such as "this implies"

Comment: "*Is it valid to assume that adding $\vee x\notin B$ would not change the original statement?*"  It is valid to assume that the statement without the or will imply the statement with the or.  $P\implies P\vee Q$.  They are however different logical expressions and the implication does not go both ways.

Comment: @JMoravitz When simplifying the expression what transition words can I use instead of writing 'Simplifying to'